# How to generate random numbers in two different arrays?(C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, random

i'm trying to generate different numbers in two different arrays and for some reason the numbers in the two arrays are the same.

this is my code:

```
#define SIZE 5

void main(){

int* num1;
int* num2;

num1 = new int[SIZE];
num2 = new int[SIZE];

random(num1);
random(num2);
int i;
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    cout << num1[i];

cout << endl;

for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    cout << num2[i];}
```

and the random function :

```
void random(int* num){

int i;

time_t t;
srand((unsigned)time(&t));

for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++ )
    num[i] = (rand() % MAX + 1);}
```

the ouput always will be the same 5-digit number in the two array 
(for example array 1 will be 29384 and array 2 also 29384)

any idea how can I solve it?

thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you have tagged this correctly as C++? It looks like to you are doing a lot of effort to only use C-like code.

Comment: You need to move the call to `srand` outside `random` and put it in `main`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the program works so fast this line

```
srand((unsigned)time(&t));
```

is likely to be seeing the random number generator with the same value.

Put this line at the start after `int main()` (there is a mistake using `void`)

Comment: I feel so stupid right now :( it works! thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

You should only call `srand` once before starting to use `rand`.

Right now, the code runs so fast that you get the same time value for both calls.

Answer (score 2):

> srand((unsigned)time(&t));

You should move this call to `main`.